# Change style/color of a only word in textarea? NOT DIV

Tags: javascript, html, colors, textarea

This may be absurd. But I was following step by step some tutorial codes to change color the `textarea` box while I was texting, and works fine (changes the text to uppercase and red while writing), but I want only one word to change. In another question, they use `div` tag elements, but I want to use `textarea` tag element. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

So, this is the code:

```js
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keypress", colors);

function colors() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text");
  var word = document.getElementById("text").value;
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
  x.style.color = "red";
  
}
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="text">Some text</textarea>
```

Comment: you mean `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");` ?

Comment: Which word do you want to change `color` property of?

Comment: x.style.color apply to all the text, I want only one word inside the text.

Comment: Which word do you want to change `color` property of?

Comment: maybe word.indexOf('World!') from "Hello World!  ?

Comment: The words would need to be on different lines within `<textarea>` element to utilize `css` pseudo selectors, for example, `:first-line`, else the full `.value` would be evaluated as a single `.value` of text.

Comment: so I use split()?

Comment: Another option would be to create a separate `<textarea>` for each word; you could then set `color` property for `<textarea>` having specific `.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do this with a textarea. Fortunately you can use a div to emulate a textarea so you can still edit within it by adding `contenteditable="true"` to the tag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: I really wanted to avoid DIV, but guess I'll have to stick with reality.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<textarea>` element for each word, use `if` condition withing `colors` function to set `color` at `style` attribute for that specific `<textarea>` element `.value`.

```css
textarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 16px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="text1" class="text">Hello </textarea><textarea name="text2" class="text">World</textarea>
<script>
  var textareas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

  for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    textareas[i].addEventListener("keypress", colors);
  }

  function colors() {
    if (this.value.indexOf("World") > -1) {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
      this.style.color = "red";
    }
  }
</script>
```